# InputMismatchException при работе со сканнером

Tags: java, исключения, scanner, buffer

Почему возникает ошибка, если раскомментировать закомментированную строку?

В файле одна строка точно такая же, как присваивается переменной `line`.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("\"" + line + "\"");
    // line = "376 933";
    System.out.println("\"" + line + "\"");
    int n1;
    int n2;
    try (Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line)) {
        n1= lineScanner.nextInt();
        n2= lineScanner.nextInt();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ошибка

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864) at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485) at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117) at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076) at
>   Metro.readMetro(Metro.java:21) at
>   Metro.main(Metro.java:64) "376 933"
>   "376 933"

Comment: в этом коде сканер не должен выдавать ошибку за исключением случаев, когда передаваемая строка содержит что-либо иное, нежели 2 цифры. опубликуйте текст вашей ошибки, пожалуйста

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at Metro.readMetro(Metro.java:21)
 at Metro.main(Metro.java:64)
"376 933"
"376 933"

Comment: что-то ваш баг невоспроизводимый... у меня этот код работает независимо от того закомментирована строка или нет. в принципе, вполне ожидаемо. пробуйте создать новый класс с методом мейн , скопировать этот код и запустить. ну и в этой закоммнетированной строке попробуйте удалить все символы и заново набить цифры  через пробел. может какие проблемы с кодировкой...

Answer (score 1):

Таки в кодировке была проблема. Файл изначально на франц. языке с их дополнительными буквами. Но причем тут строка с числами и пробелом я не понял. Цифры и пробел ведь это обычные символы из первых 127...

Comment: пробел не всегда, есть очень много разных пробельных символов в различных кодировках, есть так же много не читаемых символов

Answer (score 0):

Очень странно, я запустил следующий код у себя

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "376 933";
        System.out.println("\"" + line + "\"");
        int n1;
        int n2;
        try (Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line)) {
            n1= lineScanner.nextInt();
            n2= lineScanner.nextInt();
        }
       System.out.println(n1);
       System.out.println(n2);
}
```

**Результат**:

```
"376 933"
376
933
```

И никаких ошибок.

Попробуйте запустить мой код, выглядит так как будто у вас не тот класс исполняется или у файла класса, какая-то хитрая кодировка от чего пробел не распознается как пробел в Java.

Comment: Этот код работает. Ошибка тогда, когда читаю файл.