# Не производится запись в файл

Tags: java

Не создается сам файл и запись в него не производится. Как можно исправить?

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
File myfile =new File("text.txt");

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(myfile);

writer.write("Hello");
writer.close();
```

}

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException эта ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, такие ли же у вас импорты:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
```

Если с импортами всё в порядке, то попробуйте вывести в консоль текущий рабочий каталог

```
  System.out.println("Working Directory = " +
                System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Код опубликованный вами я проверил, у меня файл создался в корневой папке проекта.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо. А как записать в файл полученное значение? Выдает ошибку.    public static void main (String args[]) throws java.io.IOException{
        File myfile =new File("text.txt");


        FileReader reader = new FileReader(myfile);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(reader);
     int str = scan.nextInt();
     int str2 = scan.nextInt();
     int sum = str+str2;
        reader.close();
       
        
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println(str2);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(myfile); writer.write(sum);writer.close();
    }

Comment: Если у вас вылетета ошибка Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException, то нужно было её ввести в google, и сразу бы нашли вот этот [ответ](
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/746530/inputmismatchexception-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC) Если задаёте вопрос, то всегда нужно указывать какая именно ошибка